# How do I copy specific file types with Maid?

Tags: ruby, copy, fileutils, maid

I'm a first time Ruby user (any programming code for that matter) and I'm trying to create a script within "maid" to copy all of my music from a specific folder into the "automatically add to itunes" folder:

```
rule 'Move Downloaded Music to iTunes' do
    FileUtils.cp_r '/Users/*********/Movies/*********/Music/.',
    '/Users/*********/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/',
    :remove_destination => true
  end
```

However, I have non-music files within that same folder and I want to include only files with audio formats (mp3, m4a, etc.)

How can I append this code so that I can choose which file types are copied?

Additionally, what is the difference between cp_r and cp?

Any advice or improvements to my code are more than welcome - I've seen people try to do similar things with much more complicated code, so in a sense I'm worried mine is too simple...Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Maid provides some helper methods](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/benjaminoakes/maid/master/Maid/Tools) that would assist with this.  Let's piece them together, individually.

```
# Find all files in your Downloads
dir('~/Downloads/*')

# Find **any kind of audio files** in your Downloads
where_content_type(dir('~/Downloads/*'), 'audio')

# Copy these specific MP3 files in Downloads to a specific iTunes folder
copy(['~/Downloads/song_1.mp3', '~/Downloads/song_2.mp3'],
     '~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/')

# Copy any MP3 files in Downloads to a specific iTunes folder
copy(dir('~/Downloads/*.mp3'),
     '~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/')
```

We can put those pieces together for the full intent, namely copying audio files to the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder.

```
Maid.rules do
  rule 'copy audio files to the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder' do
    copy(where_content_type(dir('~/Downloads/*'), 'audio'),
       '~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/')
  end
end
```

If you'd like, this can be broken down using variables -- it's Ruby after all.

```
Maid.rules do
  rule 'copy audio files to the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder' do
    files_in_downloads = dir('~/Downloads/*')
    audio_files_in_downloads = where_content_type(files_in_downloads, 'audio')
    automatically_add_to_itunes_folder = '~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/'

    copy(audio_files_in_downloads, automatically_add_to_itunes_folder)
  end
end
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Dir::glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to find the files and [`FileUtils::mv`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mv) to move them:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob('/Users/.../Music/*.{mp3,m4a}') do |filename|
  FileUtils.mv(filename, '/Users/.../Automatically Add to iTunes/')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy special type files, use

```
Dir.foreach(absolute_path) do |file|
  if file.downcase.end_with?('.mp3', 'mp4', ....)
      FileUtils.cp(file, final_dir)
  end
end
```

Travel all folder to select which file can copy instead copying all folder by your code.

Ps: `cp_r` and `cp` is equal to `cp -r` and `cp` in console, means copy a folder or only a file.

Comment: Is there a way to retain the folders that the files are found in when I copy?  Each music file is in a folder based on artist within the src folder.

It also seems that my code is not preventing duplicate copies...

Comment: Yes, `FileUtils.cp_r` or `FileUtils.cp` is just copy folder or files but not delete source, unless using `FileUtils.mv_r` or `FileUtils.mv`